# IGraph select performance

Tags: python, igraph

I created an `iGraph.Graph`:

```
>> g.summary()
'IGRAPH DN-- 12120181 35746070 -- \n+ attr: name (v), rel (e)'
```

And I'd like to execute quite a simple query:

```
def find(source:str, rel:str):
    sel = g.es.select(_source=g.vs.find(source).index, rel_eq=rel)
    if sel:
        return [g.vs[res.target].attributes()['name'] for res in sel]
    else:
        raise ValueError('Not Found')
```

This takes an enormous amount of time:

```
%%time
>> find(source='Q43416', rel='P569')
Wall time: 17.8 s
```

Am I doing something wrong, or maybe there are some tips how to improve the performance?

Thank you in advance!

Machine: win10, 96 GB RAM, Xeon X5650; python 3.6.

....

I decided to implement the search using `Graph.incident()` like this:

```
def find2(source:Union[int, str], rel:str):
    inc = g.incident(source, mode="out")
    rels = map(lambda x: (x, g.es[x].attributes()['rel']), inc)
    found = filter(lambda x: x[1] == rel, rels)
    targets = map(lambda x: g.es[x[0]].target, found)
    targets_names = map(lambda x: g.vs[x].attributes()['name'], targets)
    return list(targets_names)
```

And it turns out that I get the result almost immediately:

```
%%time
>> find2(10537653, 'P569')
Wall time: 0 ns
```

It's ok for me to use that solution, but it raises a question: why does `select` work so much longer? If you could explain me that, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm a bit late to the party, but here's the explanation. `select()` is basically almost always doing a linear scan on the vertex or edge set being filtered, and unfortunately there is no optimized path within the code of `select()` that would handle your case. The order of the evaluation of arguments is not guaranteed either, so either `select()` is first scanning your network linearly to find all edges that originate from the source node, and then find all the ones among the selection that have the desired relation, *or* even worse, it is finding all the edges first that have the given relation and then select the ones that originate from the desired source.

The reason why your hand-crafted code is faster is because `.find()` uses an internal index on the name attribute (`name` is a special attribute in igraph that is always indexed in a hash table), finds the desired node in O(1) amortized time, and then getting the incident edges is easy from there on.

Ideally, `select()` should recognize that this is a faster way of doing what you wanted; more precisely, if `select() is operating on`g.es`(and not some pre-filtered subset of`g.es`), there are no positional arguments, _and_`_source`is somewhere among the keyword arguments, it should realize that it can use`find()` to find the appropriate set of edges quicker than the default case. Unfortunately I haven't had time to develop igraph further so this particular issue has been lingering around for a while now.

The good news is that the development of igraph and python-igraph is gaining momentum again, so I'm hoping to get this fixed in the next few days and then make a proper release of python-igraph 0.8 after nearly five years.

Comment: If you have time, would you  be so kind to loot at:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/61619829/625396